# Can an android webviews share html local storage with webviews in other apps for the same html url

Tags: android, html, android-webview, android-browser

I have searched around an cannot seem to if multiple native apps with webviews accessing the same html5 app can get the same html5 local storage.  As a follow-up question, can the local storage be shared with the local default browser?

Comment: I'm **guessing** that it shouldn't be possible, as different native apps run under different usernames in different folders. There might be an exception for WebView, but possibly not.

Comment: I see and I bet I cannot run two apps as the same username.  I will have some fun prototyping this weekend to find out.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is **possible** to run two programs under the same user name, using `android:sharedUserId` in the `AndroidManifest.xml`. But that is not a common thing to do, could make things complex.